# Inserting image loses PDF content

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to insert an image in an existing PDF file but iText puts it on the first page and I'm losing the rest of the page content. How can I insert it without losing existing content?

I used this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
          "/home/amira/work/APPS-579/word/generatedMergedDocs/FinalTest/1.pdf"));
        document.open();

        Image image = Image.getInstance(
          "/home/amira/work/APPS-579/word/generatedMergedDocs/FinalTest/a.jpg");
        document.add(image);     
    } catch (DocumentException de) {
        de.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're adding the image to an empty document, because you're not reading the original document, just overwriting it.

To modify an existing document with itext with an image, please see the following [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/modifying-pdf-documents.html) which explains it perfectly.